# Android java - making 1 ImageAdapter for 2 or more viewpagers (currently 2 adapters for 2 viewpagers)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I made an ImageAdapter class that contains images and an activity that contains 2 buttons, on click each one opens a new activity with a viewpager. The 2 viewpagers have different images and this is where my inexperience comes in.

I took the easy way and duplicated the ImageAdapter (named it ImageAdapter2) and linked it to the 2nd viewpager. [visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZJU.jpg)

It works fine, but what I'm trying to do is clean it up and do it all through 1 adapter and 1 viewpager. I tried to do it through Intent getStringExtra but it didn't recognize Intent method. Here are my classes:

ImageAdapter (**ImageAdapter2 is the same, just has different images in sliderImageId**):

```
    package hr.cnzd.prepoznajmoenasilje;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


    public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context mContext;

        ImageAdapter(Context context){
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o){
            return view == ((ImageView) o);
        }

        private int[] sliderImageId = new int[]{
                R.drawable.djeca01, R.drawable.djeca02, R.drawable.djeca03, R.drawable.djeca04, R.drawable.djeca05, R.drawable.djeca06, R.drawable.djeca07, R.drawable.djeca08
        };

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setImageResource(sliderImageId[position]);
            ((ViewPager) viewGroup).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position, Object o){
            ((ViewPager) viewGroup).removeView((ImageView) o);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return  sliderImageId.length;
        }

    }
```

Activity with buttons:

```
package hr.cnzd.prepoznajmoenasilje;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MA_Savjeti extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton imageButtonDjeca;
    private ImageButton imageButtonOdrasli;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ma__savjeti);

        imageButtonDjeca = findViewById(R.id.imgBtnDjeca);
        imageButtonDjeca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivitySavjetiDjeca();
            }
        });

        imageButtonOdrasli = findViewById(R.id.imgBtnOdrasli);
        imageButtonOdrasli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivitySavjetiOdrasli();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivitySavjetiDjeca() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Savjeti_Djeca.class);
        intent.putExtra("savjeti", "djeca");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openActivitySavjetiOdrasli() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Savjeti_Odrasli.class);
        intent.putExtra("savjeti", "odrasli");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Activity with viewpager (other activity with viewpager has the same code, just calls ImageAdapter2)

```
package hr.cnzd.prepoznajmoenasilje;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class Savjeti_Djeca extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.savjeti_djeca);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

}
```

**TLDR**: I have 2 ImageAdapters and 2 Viewpagers, but I wanna do it through 1 ImageAdapter and 1 Viewpager (2 buttons on a previous activity decide which set of images is shown on the viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using ViewPager2 instead of this way.